# How to refer to json file added to Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is a very newbie type question. I have added a JSON file using **add new item** to my project. Now in my C# code I want basically 'use' this file. How to refer to this file? Basically I am trying to POST it to a WebAPI, something of this sort:-

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.somePOSTtypefunction(MyJSONfile);
```

How do I do this? At least I would like to know how to refer to such a file in C# code in general. I don't want to hardcode the JSON data in the code.

Comment: can you please specify what kind of project are you working on? Xamarin project? WebAPI? WPF?

Comment: it's a simple console application for now. I didn't know it varies from project type to type. For now I would just like to know for console application.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be safer side to avoid any file level exception, include in using as :

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/path/to/some.json")))
{
      client.somePOSTtypefunction(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a console application:

1. Add your json file to solution
2. Set *Build Action* to *EmbeddedResource*
3. You can access the file via:

   ```
   var jsonPath = "JSONTest.Resources.sample.json"; //your path to the JSONfile
   var jsonStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(jsonPath);

   string jsonString;
   using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(jsonStream))
   {
       jsonString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();            
       Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
   }
   ```
4. You can parse your JSON to object with:

   ```
   var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObject>(jsonString);
   ```
5. Do whatever you want with your JSON object ;-)

Comment: r & s are not defined there, what are they?

Comment: @Dhiraj sorry, you are right. I've changed my answer

Comment: @lawiluk thanks for your answer. would you please be able to elaborate on why it's an "embedded resource"?